# How to animate image size inside a flutter container without changing the container height and width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to apply the animation to the image size which is inside a flutter AnimatedContainer widget without changing the container height and width.

But, in the below code I am able to achieve this by changing the height and width of the container. Whereas I want the container height and width should be fixed and the animation should be only applied to the image size.

Is there a way to achieve this with fixed container height and width?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScaleAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Scale Animation")),
      body: ImageAnimation(),
    );
  }
}

class ImageAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageAnimationState createState() => _ImageAnimationState();
}

class _ImageAnimationState extends State<ImageAnimation> {
  bool isTapped = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isTapped = !isTapped;
          });
        },
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          height: isTapped ? 350.0 : 300.0,
          width: isTapped ? 350 : 300.0,
          alignment:
              isTapped ? Alignment.center : AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 100.0, 50.0, 100.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black54,
                blurRadius: 100.0, // soften the shadow
              )
            ],
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/images/thumb/cup_noun_002_09489.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works

```
class ImageAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageAnimationState createState() => _ImageAnimationState();
}

class _ImageAnimationState extends State<ImageAnimation> {
  bool isTapped = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isTapped = !isTapped;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black54,
                blurRadius: 100.0, // soften the shadow
              )
            ],
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              height: isTapped ? 200.0 : 100.0,
              width: isTapped ? 200 : 100.0,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/images/thumb/cup_noun_002_09489.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: an improvement would be to also explain some of the code to @Hrusikesh Bunu so that he can learn better :)

Comment: I would definitely appreciate your help understanding me flutter in a better way @Nuqo btw I am new to flutter and instead of the comment if you can help me with my problem it would be really great help!